# Error dynamically updating an array list in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning reactJS and so I am trying my hands on an example. This example has a form textfield that can add an item to an existing array on click of a button. I am having errors here as when I enter a text and click on the button, the array list is not updated except I try to make changes to the text entered in the textfield. This is what I am doing:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentName : '',
      arrays : ['john', 'james', 'timothy']
    }   
  }
  render() {
    const showNames =   this.state.arrays.map((thisName) => {
        const values = <li>{thisName}</li>;
        return values;
     }); 
    const getText = (e) => {
        let value = e.target.value;
        this.setState({
          currentName : value
        })
    }
    const addToUsers =  () => {
      this.state.arrays.push(this.state.currentName)
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <p>Add new name to List</p><br/>
        <form>
          <input type="text"  onChange={getText}/>
          <button type="button" onClick={addToUsers}>Add User</button> 

        </form>
        <ul>
          {showNames}
        </ul>
      </div>

    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure you update state using the `setState` method.

When you update `arrays` you are reaching into the state object and manipulating the data directly instead of using the method.

Instead try something like:

```
const addToUsers =  () => {
  const newArray = this.state.arrays.concat([this.state.currentName]);
  this.setState({
    arrays: newArray
  });
}
```

Comment: This works but I had tried something similar to this while debugging. I noticed you used concat() instead of push(). Why is this so?

Comment: @radioactive `push` modifies an existing array, while `concat` constructs a new array. We could alternatively create a copy of the array, and then push to that before using it in `setState`

Answer (score 3):

There are a host of things wrong with this, but your issue is likely that you need to use `setState` to modify state.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();

    this.state = {
      names: ['john', 'james', 'timothy']
    }
  }

  addToUsers = () => {
    this.setState(
      prevState => ({
        names: [...prevState.names, this.input.value]
      })
    )
  }

  render() {
    const names = this.state.names.map(
      (name, index) => <li key={index}>{name}</li>
    )

    return (
      <div>
        <p>Add new name to List</p><br/>

        <form>
          <input type="text" ref={e => this.input = e} />
          <button type="button" onClick={this.addToUsers}>Add User</button> 
        </form>

        <ul>
          {names}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

This quick edit changes a few things:

1. Uses `setState` for the `addToUsers` method
2. Eliminate `onChange` tracking and pull the name directly from the input when the button is clicked
3. Move the `addToUsers` method out to the component class rather than defining it on `render`
4. Rename `this.state.arrays` to `this.state.names`
5. Simplify conversion of `this.state.names` into list items
6. Set `key` on array elements (name list items)
7. Use `prevState` in `setState` to avoid race conditions

Comment: push returns the total length of the array not the updated array, so this will not work as expected. `names: this.state.names.push(this.input.value)` :)

Comment: @MayankShukla Good catch, I'm too used to Ruby. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably must add

```
onChange={getText}.bind(this)
```

to your functions. 
Also change this

```
const addToUsers =  () => {
      this.state.arrays.push(this.state.currentName)
    }
```

to this

```
const addToUsers =  () => {
      this.setState({here put your variable})
    }
```